# Change image at client side too after change at server side

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an embedded program that is changing an image at server side when submit button pressed. At serverside it is completely works but at client side when I'm refreshing pressing F5 then only the change occurs. I am using wordpress and one page is having`<img src="path">`. I am new in wordpress and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit advanced for someone new to php but most commonly either long polling or websockets is used to force a client to update from the server.

There are some good explanations to be found here: [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)